# when is the UI ready to start animating an UIActivityIndicatorView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I try to start an UIActivityIndicatorView at the beginning of my App but it doesn't animte!

code in my root view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *v = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    [self.view addSubview:v];
    [v startAnimating];
}
```

Doesn't spin. I tried `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`, not better.

If I do a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, when I reach something like 4 or 5 sec of delay now it work... Like there is something not initialized in UIKit.

Anyone have an idea ?

**Update:**
I can wait as long as I want -> it never start spinning (so nothing taking time on MainThread and blocking this spinning). I actually removed almost everything from my AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. No more RestKit init, no more PushNotification registration. Only ViewController init. And those ViewController do nothing.

But what I can do is this:
add a dummy button on the interface that do nothing (no IBAction No IBOutlet nothing) and just touch it on the iPhone. It go to highlighted and then normal. But as soon as I touch it (even before I quit the surface of the screen) the spinning wheel start to spin!

What is happening here ??

Comment: Don't you need to give it a frame?

Comment: I simplified the code to the essential... here it will be at top left but it's not important. It appear, just it doesn't spin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! After 1.5 days of tracking this issue...

My MainViewController, embedded in a NavigationController, is showing the activity indicator in its `viewDidLoad`.

It so happen that in the same `viewDidLoad` I pushed some splash screen onto the NavigationController and it messed with the views somehow.

I was using, in my SplashViewController `doFlip` method (called automatically after some delay, ~2 sec):

```
[UIView transitionWithView:navController.view
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{ [nc popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; }
                completion:nil];
```

and now use

```
[UIView transitionFromView:splashVC.view
                    toView:mainVC.view
                  duration:0.75 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:nil];

[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Sorry for the "too specific", and thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code, it animates right away for me. Are you loading anything synchronously as soon as the app opens? That could cause a delay.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are using this code because when your app loads up, it does something that will take a while.  If it is doing this thing on the main thread (as it should be unless you have specified otherwise) then your user interface will become unresponsive while it is performing that task, including freezing all animations.  To push the task on to another thread, you must use Apple's Grand Central Dispatch (GCD).  To do that use something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t myLongTaskQueue = dispatch_queue_create("AnyIdentifyingText", NULL);
dispatch_async(myLongTaskQueue, ^{

     //perform the long task

});
```

Then if somewhere in the long task you have to update the UI, make sure you do this back in the main thread by using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    //perform UI update

});
```

Comment: I know about that. Normally it's okay. But in between PushNotification, RestKit init etc... maybe somewhere something is happening. But I have done a pause in Xcode and checked on the main thread what is happening. It seems nothing... but I will double check today. Thanks.